# Taking double arguments from command line

Tags: c

Here is a simple program that converts Fahrenheit to Celsius in C, it scans for the input of the Fahrenheit degree which is fine, but I want to take arguments directly from the terminal, so
**Expected behavior** would be using `./temperature.c 40` and **Expected output** would be `40.00 Fahrenheit is equal to 4.44 Celsius`

```
int main(int argc, double argv[])
{
        double celsius;
        double fahrenheit;
        fahrenheit = argv[1];
        printf("Enter the temperature here in Fahrenheit: ");
/*      scanf("%lf", &fahrenheit);*/
        celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9 ;
        printf("%.2lf fahrenheit is equal to %.2lf celsius\n", fahrenheit, celsius);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must declare `argv` as `char* argv[]` (You get an array of string pointers from the commandline). From there, you can use functions to convert a string to a double, such as [`strtod`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtod.htm).

ps: you should check if the user actually specified the temperature you expect from the command line :

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage : %s <temperature in fahrenheit>", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    // convert argv[1] to  double

    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i.e. automatic conversion of command line parameters to other types is not possible.